# Codeigniter Forum Integration

Tags: codeigniter, forum

I'd like to integrate a simple forum with a Codeigniter application and wondered if anyone had any recommendations? Cheers

Laurence

Comment: What sort of 'integration' are you talking about? Something like SSO? Or are you looking for a library?

Comment: Just for the person who fav'd this, I ended up writing a simple forum from scratch. If you are interested I'd be happy to whack it up on Google Code or Github.

Comment: @LaurenceDawson: I wasn't the first person who fav'd your question, but I am interested in the solution you developed. Would you still be open to putting up the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would take a look at vanilla forums, lots of addons, open source, and pretty easy to integrate things with (ie Codeigniter)

http://vanillaforums.org/

there are a few forum topics on how to do things with ci and vanilla

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/134946/

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/FreakAuth-Vanilla-integration--an-auth-lib-and-a-forum-engine-

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CL-Auth-Integration-with-Vanilla-Forum-Engine

Comment: I have question about that integration. With CI rewrite vanilla's CSS are messed up. It's in subdir of main dir.