# What forum i can integrate with codeigniter and they sessions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, forum

i am using something like this:

```
$this->session->userdata('name');
```

and etc.. i want to use this sessions in the integrated forum, to use one session in the site and in the forum...

is there a fast & easy way to put a ready forum in codeIgniter?, just like in joomla or others CMS??

Because writing my own forum will cost much time.... is there a fast way??

Comment: This has likely been done already - have you done a web search for "CodeIgniter forum integration"?

Comment: Also to note, Code Igniter is a framework, __not__ a cms. But do a google for your specific forum and Code Igniter integration. E.g. "smf Code Igniter integration"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any forum in codeigniter php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523151/is-there-any-forum-in-codeigniter-php)

Answer (score 1):

There are several forum options. read more:

1. [Codeigniter Forum Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168449/codeigniter-forum-integration)
2. [Is there any forum in codeigniter php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523151/is-there-any-forum-in-codeigniter-php)